# Is there a way to create two or more smart lists on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

Here's an example,
I want to create two different education smart lists. Both of the same type, but different. Is there a way? Because there are times when Facebook does create two Work smart lists, so this should be possible. But the question is, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you list two or more schools in the education section of your profile/timeline, a smart list will be created for each one.